# URL Rewrite JS/CSS is not working with AEM

Tags: javascript, css, url-rewriting, aem

I'm working with **AEM 6.0** and I'm trying to configure URL rewrite for some resources like images, css and js to serve them from a different domain.

I modified the bundle "Day CQ Link Checker Transformer" to add all the elements and properties to rewrite:

[tags and properties to rewrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RPxV.png)

But when I go to see the page only the rewrite for images is working but CSS and JS are not working.

Is only for author instance.

Can you help me???

Comment: We are facing similar issue, but our author and publish both instances are working fine. Only our production instance is not picking up resources correctly.